# Simulating keyboard ghosting on FreePIE

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to simulate keyboard ghosting for a Windows game on FreePIE (Free Programming Input Editor) for people who have anti-ghosting keyboards. In this game, ghosting on the up and down keys, or whatever keys are used for up-down movement, is very helpful in performing a needed technique on a specific character.

This used to be done in another program, GlovePIE, which has essentially the same functions, with this simple script:

```
if pressed(key.Down)
key.Up = false
endif
```

However, GlovePIE won't work anymore because of a game update, so I want to do something similar on FreePIE. I've tried looking around on their documentation, but in recent years FreePIE has changed their fundamental coding to Python, meaning most of the old documentation is outdated.

---

Can anyone help out a bit? Trying to mimic the few Python FreePIE examples I found around, I was thinking of something like

```
if pressed(keyboard.getKeyDown):
<indent> ???? key up being able to be pressed = false
```

...but as can be seen from the example, I have no idea how to really complete it, or if a "pressed()" function exists in FreePIE... though I do know using "keyboard" module is how you call the keys, rather than "key" in GlovePIE.